# How to reduce the default metadata size for an XFS file system?

Tags: linux, filesystems, xfs

I have a special-purpose 12-disk volume, 48 TB total. After *mkfs* with default parameters, mounting using inode_64,
the reported available space for files is 44 TB. So there is 4 TB metadata overhead, almost 10%.

I'm thinking this metadata size is probably intended to accomodate tens of millions of inodes, whereas I use only large files
and would need 1-2 million files max. Given this, my question is *whether it's possible to recover 2-3 TB out of the 4 TB metadata, to use for file data*.

In the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.xfs) I see a *maxpct* option, possibly others, but I cannot figure out what is the correct way to use them
in my case. I still need to make sure that the volume can hold the 2 million files.
Also, I understand some metadata space is used for journaling and here I don't know how much would be enough.

Comment: Are you sure that space is actually missing, or are you being misled by [the difference between binary and decimal units of storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#Deviation_between_powers_of_1024_and_powers_of_1000)? That comes out to almost exactly 10% at the terabyte range.

Comment: Yes, this appears to be the case, indeed. Then after recalculating strictly in bytes, the reserved metadata is quite negligible, in the order of 2 GB. If so, since I'm not going to create more files than I need, I'm thinking I don't even need to mess with the file system settings. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, cool. I've written this up as an answer with some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the specific percentage of storage that you're seeing missing, it seems likely that you're being misled by [the difference between binary and decimal units of storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#Deviation_between_powers_of_1024_and_powers_of_1000). Since disks are measured in decimal terabytes, using software tools that measure available storage in binary terabytes (which are 10% larger) will give you results that appear to be about 9% too low. The storage hasn't actually gone anywhere, though; you're just using units that make it look smaller!

By default, the coreutils versions of the `df` and `du` commands use binary units. You can use the `-H` flag to make them use decimal units instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could drop it from 5% to 1%.

maxpct
This specifies the maximum percentage of space in the filesystem that can be allocated to inodes. The default value is 25% for filesystems under 1TB, 5% for filesystems under 50TB and 1% for filesystems over 50TB.

Just keep in mind that tuning a filesystem is a tricky affair. There's a delicate balance achieved between stability, reliability, and performance.